# Meteor client modify code

Tags: meteor

Many tutorials say to place some code in lib/file.js where it can run on both client and server.
Does that also allow the client to modify the code as they like?  Thanks

Comment: Only if they hack into your server.

Comment: As others have stated, no. However, as with any client side JS, there's nothing to prevent them from using the debugger to step through your client side code and modify the values of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer to clarify what David is saying below:

You can change the definitions of any client-side accessible code you want.  Server code itself cannot be changed while it's running unless you're using `eval()` or are able to mess with the file system from the client. This is important because even if you change the client code to do something that would potentially look malicious, the server code wouldn't execute that code as such since they are defined in two completely separate places (your machine on the client versus the actual server) If you mean can the client can see the code being executed, then yes, they'll be able to see the minified version of anything in lib/file.js.

Comment: This answer is on track, but the first two sentences are confusing. Are you saying the client can't modify its own code? If so, that isn't true because you can open up a console and overwrite any function you like.

Comment: Hey David - you're right, that was definitely confusing when I went back to look at it.  I edited the answer based on my understanding.  If you disagree/know any of that is incorrect, add an answer and I'll toss you an upvote.